# How to save the location of a component that has been previously clicked on on a GridLayout

Tags: java, arrays, swing, location

I'm making a little game in java called ColorLine

(the game : http://www.gamesforthebrain.com/french/colorlines/ )

so I made a JFrame and added to it a gridLayout of JPanels (two dimensions array) and the pieces are represented by JButtons which are added to the JPanels. and I want to move the JButtons from a panel to another using mouseClicked method in MouseInputListener interface, by clicking on the button, then clicking on the empty panel (destination) but I have no idea how to save the location of the the button that has been clicked first especially how to transform the location into x, y coordinates in order to use them for my two dimensions array of Jpanels
thanks :)

Comment: This is not a help site but rather a question and answer site. In order to make this question and its answers benefit all future visitors, please post pertinent code, preferably a [mcve], with your question and not in a link.

Answer (score 2):

You could structure the code in a way similar to what the common Model-View-Controller pattern suggests.

- Make sure that you have a central game model object that holds the game state and provides callback methods like `tileClicked(Tile tile)` and eventually listeners for the views.
- Extend the JPanels (the views) you insert into the grid to custom tiles (e.g. class Tile extends JPanel).
- Save the xy-position of a tile in the corresponding tile-object as field(s) via a constructor or setter-method when setting up the game board.
- Add the listeners you need (mouse, action, ...) within the Tile-class to each Tile object (for example using inner classes) and call a fitting callback method of your game model. 
  For example (analogous for mouse listener): 
  `button.addActionListener(e -> gameModel.tileClicked(this));`
- This way the game model receives all information it needs to determine the next game state and manipulate the relevant views. For example: the user clicks on a button -> the event is sent to the tile the button belongs to -> the tile informs the model that its button has been clicked -> the user clicks on the empty panel -> the mouse event is sent to the panel/tile that has been clicked -> the tile informs the model that it has been clicked -> now the game model knows which tiles got clicked, can retrieve tile-properties like the tile position via getter-methods from the tiles and manipulate the tiles via setter-methods accordingly.

Comment: A decent answer for a not so decent (yet) question. On behalf of other stack overflow users, thank you, and 1+.

Answer (score 0):

Use Two dimensional arrays to keep track of the `Button`s or the `JPanel`s. So something like this `JPanel [][] jp = new JPanel[9][9];`
so that for the first jpanel in the gridlayout can be assigned like this

```
jp[0][0] = new JPanel();
jp[0][1] = new JPanel();
......
jp[8][8] = new JPanel();
```

Or you can you `for loop` to initialize each `JPanel`.